# how to keep a session alive using a shared server? ASP.NET / MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session

Currently my web application is hosted in a shared server (asphostcentral) with the following configuration (web.config):

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" cookieless="UseCookies">
```

After some time, the session expires, the users are redirected to login page and forced to enter their credentials again.

The answer I received from support is:

> As this is a shared server, you are advised not to use session state.
>   Instead, please use cookie. The way you program cookie is very, very
>   similar to session, except, the implementation is different.
>
> On a shared server, there are other sites on the server that may
>   impact your site sessions.

can anyone assist on this? do you how to implement the solution provided by support team?

Comment: thanks for your answers. This was the solution: http://geekfreeq.ventaur.com/aspnet-remember-me-option-forms-authentication-not-working/

machineKey inside web.config was neeeded. This works for web farms scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

> you are advised not to use session state

So <kbd>Ctrl+F</kbd> in your solution and remove all traces of `Session` from your code. If you need to store some information for the user and this information is sensitive you could either store it into the database and query it later or use the userData portion of the authentication cookie. It will all depend how are you currently using the session.

Comment: @MuhammadAdeelZahid, because Session makes you write stateful applications that do not scale well. Because Session by default is stored in memory of a given web server which means that if your AppDomain is recycled (which could happen at any time) you will lose information. Because if you run in a web-farm with many nodes, if you store the Session in memory of a given node, other nodes won't be able to access it. You will have to use an out-of-proc session in this case. There are so many reasons that you shouldn't use session.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov- Would you take time so that you share us all possible reasons as why not to use session? You can update your answer. Thank you.

Comment: @nuux, I've already shared some of the reasons in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Using a cookie instead of the session is dangerous advice. Please do not take it literally. Cookies can be read and forged by clients and have a size limit.

You can:

1. Use ASP.NET session state server on a shared server. That way your web machines can share the session.
2. Use sticky sessions
3. Remove all usages of the session. You can either store stuff in the database or a cookie (which I do not recommend!)

I recommend, in order, these three solutions.